# Store FormData object on localStorage HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I'm trying to save some data to localStorage on my offline application. When user on offline mode, then browser will collect data from form, FormData object, store it to localStorage and when browser is online then it will push the FormData object that store in localStorage to server via jQuery ajax. The complexity is that the form have dynamic fields and can have the fileupload field and the problem is that the localStorage on html5 support data as string and not the object.

```
Collection.prototype.storeOfflineData = function(collectionId){
   var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
   pendingSites = {"collectionId" : collectionId, "formData" : formData};
   window.localStorage.setItem("offlineSites", JSON.stringify(pendingSites));
   Collection.prototype.goHome();
   Collection.prototype.showErrorMessage("Successfully store data in offline.");
}
```

When the browser is online,connected to internet, I created the methods to read FormData from local storage and make ajax request to server but ajax request got error because the JSON.parse return "[object object]"

```
Collection.prototype.pushingPendingSites = function(){
  pendingSites = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("offlineSites"));
  if(pendingSites != null){
    console.log(pendingSites[i]["formData"]);
    Collection.prototype.ajaxCreateSite(pendingSites[i]["collectionId"], pendingSites[i]["formData"]);
  }
}

Collection.prototype.ajaxCreateSite = function(collectionId, formData){
  $.ajax({
    url: '/mobile/collections/' + collectionId + '/sites',  //Server script to process data
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(){
      Collection.prototype.goHome();
      Collection.prototype.showErrorMessage("Successfully saved.");
    },
    error: function(data){
      Collection.prototype.showErrorMessage("Save new site failed!");
    },
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
  });
}
```

Comment: It works fine for me, may be the FormData object is not as per the JSON standards, can you provide what is the output for formData, just do console.log(formData)

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a FormData object instead of just storing the values of the form fields?

Comment: FormData { append=append()} but after stringify and use JSON.parse it return Object {}. I think Stringify may change the FormData object.

Comment: @Musa my form is dynamic forms. So i need a FormData object to get all the data in the form and send to server via jquery ajax.

Comment: Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/

Comment: Yes this one can apply most of my form field but not the form with fileupload field.

Comment: You'll have to store the file as a data url. Look into `FileReader`.

Comment: @Musa Thank for your idea about FileReader. I read the content of the file using FileReader readAsDataURL and send via ajax to server but it seem that imagemagick not recorgnize the format of image file. Any idea please?

Comment: You'll have to remove the url section then decode the data. `base64_decode(preg_replace('#data:.+?,#', '', $dataurl));`

Comment: @Musa it work like a charm. Thank for saving me from this nightmare. I can convert your idea from php to ruby :)

Comment: new URLSearchParams(formData).toString()